# String for section number is never empty

Tags: koma-script

I would like to add some more space between the section number and section title in a Koma script document. Editing the section line to always have added whitespace results in the obvious problem that unnumbered sections are indented a little bit. For this I thought to use a function like `\ifstrempty` form `etoolbox` to see if the section is numbered or not. But it appears that this string is never empty.

*MWE:* the following

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
    {\ifstrempty{#3}{}{#3\ }}{#4}%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

produces
[image: result]

Other methods like `\@ifnotempty` result in the same output.

Is there a proper way to check if a section is unnumbered in Koma script?

Comment: The value of `#3` for an unnumbered section is `\@empty`.  One can use an `\ifx` test to detect it, but make sure the `\else` and `\fi` don't get in the way.

Comment: Your redefinition of `\sectionlinesformat` adds the space for subsection and subsubsection headings, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: In your case, you should use the suggestion of @Ivan, ie. redefine `\sectionformat`. Then the space is inserted only for numbered sections. You can also redefine `\subsectionformat` and `\subsubsectionformat`, if these heading should get the additional space between number and title.

If you really need to check, if there is no number for a `section`, `subsection` or `subsubsection` heading, you could use `\Ifstr{#3}{}{}{\ }`. `\Ifstr` is provided by the KOMA-Script class.

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3\Ifstr{#3}{}{}{\ }}{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\addsec*{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.}

\addsec{Unnumbered Section}
\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}
\end{document}
```

Inside the definition of `\sectionlinesformat` or `\sectioncatchphraseformat` you could also use `\IfUseNumber{\ }{}`. This command is provided by the KOMA-Script class.

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3\IfUseNumber{\ }{}}{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\addsec*{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.}

\addsec{Unnumbered Section}
\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}
\end{document}
```

Note, both suggestions would add the space to numbered sections, subsections and subsubsections.

Answer (score 2):

You should redefine the `\sectionformat` command:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{showframe}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1.5em}}

\begin{document}
 \section*{Introduction}
 \section{First section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a solution via `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\sectionformat}{\enskip}{\hspace{1.5em}}{}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I add `\showtokens{#3}` in the redefinition of `\sectionformat` I get, in the case of `\section*{Introduction}`

```
> \@empty .
\sectionlinesformat #1#2#3#4->\showtokens {#3}
                                              {\ifstrempty {#3}{}{#3\ }}{#4}
l.13 \section*{Introduction}
```

and, in the case of `\section{First section}`,

```
> \@svsec .
\sectionlinesformat #1#2#3#4->\showtokens {#3}
                                              {\ifstrempty {#3}{}{#3\ }}{#4}
l.14 \section{First section}
```

So we see that the class passes `\@empty` rather than nothing when the *-variant is used. You can then use `\ifdefvoid` as the test.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
    {\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{#3\ }}{#4}%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

[image]